# Trying to concatenate strings and add integers to a sum separately

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I posted this earlier and trying to figure out if this works better in terms of presentation. I am trying to concatenate strings and sum the integers from a list separately. For some reason, I am not getting the output I expected

```
l = ['magical unicorns', 19, 'hello', 98.98, 'world']

comb_str = ''
comb_int = 0

for i in l:
    if type(i) is 'str':
        comb_str = comb_str + 'i'
    elif type(i) is 'int':
        comb_int += i
    else:
        pass

print comb_str
print comb_int
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: `if type(i) is 'str'` ==> `if type(i) is str` same for `int` and you probably want: `comb_str = comb_str + i` not `comb_str = comb_str + 'i'`

Answer (score 3):

"type(i) is 'str'" will never be True.
Try something like `isinstance(i, str)` instead. Similar for the int check. Actually, `type(i) is str` will also work. Note that str is not in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

For concatenating strings:

```
print "".join(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, basestring), l))
```

Output:

```
'magical unicornshelloworld'
```

For sum the integers:

```
import numbers
print sum(filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, numbers.Number), l))
```

Output:

```
117.98
```

Answer (score 0):

use isinstance function instead of type.
Tested code here:

```
l = ['magical unicorns', 19, 'hello', 98.98, 'world']
con=''
sum=0
for i in l:
    print (i)
    if isinstance(i, str):
       con = con+str(i)
    elif isinstance(i, int):
       sum = sum+i
    else:
       pass
print (con)
print (sum)
```